# check shared path is available in pc

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

i am working in .net compact framework 3.5.I am developing an application working in [pocket pc](http://www.activant-direct.com/aftermarket/pc/configurePrd.asp?idProduct=186). Pocket PC device should be connected to the local PC.User can create a shared folder in local PC and can send files to shared folder from [pocket pc](http://www.activant-direct.com/aftermarket/pc/configurePrd.asp?idProduct=186).I am asking the user to enter the shared folder path in my application,folder format is(\Shared-PC-Name\FolderName).I need to check whether the shared folder path entered by the user is exist in local PC.I code to send files to that local pc shared folder.I don't know how to check the folder name entered by user is exist in the local pc.

Please help me in doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
        string testString = "C:\temp";

        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(testString);
        if (di.Exists) return true;
```

I can only assume that System.IO exists within the compact framework and that it has the .Exists function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Wnet API from pocketpc and try a connect to the shared resource. There is

a) no drive letters on PocketPC

and

b) no API to check the existence of a share.

To try to connect, you use

```
DWORD WNetAddConnection3(HWND hwndOwner, LPNETRESOURCE
   lpNetResource, LPCWSTR lpPassword, LPCWSTR lpUserName,
   DWORD dwFlags);
```

with LPNETRESOURCE being:

```
typedef struct _NETRESOURCE {
   DWORD dwScope;
   DWORD dwType;
   DWORD dwDisplayType;
   DWORD dwUsage;
   LPWSTR lpLocalName;
   LPWSTR lpRemoteName;
   LPWSTR lpComment;
   LPWSTR lpProvider;
} NETRESOURCE, *LPNETRESOURCE;
```

It is similar on a PC. You can browse a remote host or you enter the URI for the shared resource, but there is no API to check for the existence of a shared resource. You may issue a NET VIEW command on the PC to list resources shared by a given domain, workgroup or host.

You may use WNetOpenEnum to get a list of shared resources and see if a resource exists in the results: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms898713.aspx

OpenNetCF's offers a .net function for you:

```
/// <summary>
/// Enumerates network resources.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="remoteName">The name of the server</param>
/// <returns>Array of NetworkResource class</returns>
public static NetworkResource[] GetNetworkResources(string remoteName)
```

it is part of the OpenNETCF.Net namespace. So you do not need to code your own p/invoke for the WNet API call you need.

see also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885813.aspx